# Creating new PostGIS table with records + geometries from another table?

Tags: qgis, postgis, attribute-table, geometry, copy

I have a bunch of PostGIS tables (one per county) containing polygons for all of the property parcels in that county. Each layer also includes several attributes like street address, property value, and acreage that I'm interested in keeping. Each layer also has several dozen columns that I don't need and want to discard. I want to merge all of the data I'm keeping from these tables into a single PostGIS table `parcels` with an additional `county` column, that looks like this:

[image]

I understand how to use `INSERT/SELECT` statements to take values from one table and insert into another, but ***I am confused about exactly what I need to do to copy the geometries from each county's layers along with the attribute data***.

Am I supposed to just copy the `geom` column along with the columns I'm interested in keeping? In addition to the `geom` field, several of the county layers have columns called `x_coord`, `y_coord`, and others have columns with names like `shape_area`, `shape_len`, `shape_star`, etc ... I'm wondering if I need to copy any of these over along with the `geom` field? Are any of these fields related to how PostGIS stores geometry data, or are these all just useless remnants from the ArcGIS tools that the counties used to generate these tables?

***What exactly is the process for copying attributes + geometry data from one PostGIS table to another?*** I'm using QGIS and would like to know how to do it with DB manager, if possible, but I'd also like to know how to do if from the `psql` command line if anyone knows how.

Just to have a concrete example, let's say I have a table called `jefferson_parcels` that contains 40+ attribute fields, but I only want to copy the fields `situs_addr, situs_city, cfmv_total, ttl_acres, land_use` from `jefferson_parcels` and `INSERT` them into the `parcels` table in the fields `parcel_addr, parcel_city, total_value, total_acres, land_use` respectively, and set the `county` field equal to `jefferson`. Along with all of this attribute data, I want to copy over the geometry data for these parcels. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data in geometry columns are independent from any other columns (what makes sense in terms of database design...) and are treated like any other data type.

You could use the following SQL to copy the data in your example:

```
    INSERT INTO parcels 
(parcel_addr, parcel_city, total_value, total_acres, land_use, county, geom)
      SELECT
        situs_addr
        , situs_city
        , cfmv_total
        , ttl_acres
        , land_use
        , 'jefferson'
        , geom
      FROM jefferson_parcels
    ;
```

See also [this similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql) on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks - like I said in the original post, I already know how to copy data from one table to another and had actually come across the post you mentioned, and tried something similar to the SQL query you wrote. It seemed to be working (just selecting `geom` along with the other columns), but I wasn't sure if there was some subtle problem I was causing by not copying over the `x_coord`, `shape_area`, `longitude`, etc fields as well, and I couldnt' find any official documentation on how to copy tables like this, or whether `geom` contained all of the geometry data.