# QGIS: Creating new geometric tables in PostGIS based on fields of another table?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a PostGIS instance in which I'm attempting to use QGIS to create 3 different geometric tables (point, line, polygon) with identical fields.

I've created the point table, but there does not seem to be a way (as in ArcGIS) to import fields using another layer's fields as a template.

I've read this: [Creating new PostGIS table with records + geometries from another table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281384/creating-new-postgis-table-with-records-geometries-from-another-table)

but I do not need to wholesale copy entire tables; I need to create new tables with different geometry types but which have the same set of fields/value types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it directly in Postgres.

use the `create like` command, and instruct to preserve the keys, constraints, default etc (but not foreign keys and triggers):

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table_name ( LIKE old_table_name INCLUDING ALL);
```

Then modify the geometry type

```sql
ALTER TABLE new_table_name ALTER COLUMN geometry TYPE geometry(polygon,4326);
```